# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

Tags: apex, visualforce

Created a VF page to create Opportunity. While saving the Opportunity on Page it is throwing exception on Account lookup **Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []**

how to resolve this issue ? can anyone please help me

**Here is my class:**

```
public class oppcreate
{

    public Opportunity opp{get; set;}
    public oppcreate ()
    {
        opp= new opportunity();

    }
    public void Saveto(){

        opportunity oppRec= new opportunity();

        oppRec.AccountId= opp.AccountID; // throwing exception on this line

        oppRec.name= opp.name;

        oppRec.closedate= opp.closedate;
        insert oppRec;
    }
}
```

**VF Page:**

```
 <apex:page Controller="oppcreate">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Edit" mode="edit">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Saveto}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <apex:pageBlockSection  title="Opportunity Information">

    <apex:inputField value="{!opp.AccountId}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!opp.name}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!opp.Closedate}"/>

    </apex:PageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>

    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you passing an ``AccountId``  to the controller? You need to force some kind of validation on the page to ensure that the user selects an account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are some useless code in your controller.

You don't need to instantiate a new opportunity in the save method. The opportunity variable which is shared with your Visualforce page have already all the values assigned.

You only have to do this:

```
public void Saveto(){
        insert opp;
    }
```

About your error, it seems that you never assigned an account to the opportunity using the VF page.
Just add some check before inserting your opportunity:

```
public void Saveto(){
            if(opp.AccountId != null && opp.Name != null){
                insert opp;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I implemented your logic but it is giving same exception

Comment: Are you selecting an Account in your VF page before clicking on the save button?

Comment: Yes I am selecting  the account

Comment: Sorry the error was with accounts not with the code. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

The field `AccountId` from `Opportunity` refears to an `Account` object.

So you need to set this field with an Account ID like this :

```
Account acc = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'XXX' LIMIT 1]; // Replace XXX by the Account name you want to retrieve

Opportunity oppRec = new Opportunity();

oppRec.AccountId= acc.Id;

insert oppRec;
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to select the Accounts which already in the system. I don't want to create any new account.

Comment: Sorry if I miss communicated .. I want to show all the accounts in the lookup (it should work as standard one), not only the specific one.